# Using exceptions for user error

Tags: java

I'm working on an IRC bot that should handle some user commands, lets take `!login <username> <password>` for example. Sometimes the user forgets to enter their password, so instead of sending `!login myUser hunter2` they might use `!login myUser`. In this case, the user should be replied to with an error message. The method that actually handles the command `handleCommand` is always wrapped by another method `wrapperMethod`. Which of the following ways should I use to handle user errors: should `handleCommand` just message the user about what happened and exit itself, or should it throw an exception with the error message and let `wrapperMethod` do the rest? (`String[] command` is the original command without the `!` and split by spaces, so `!login myUser hunter2` would become `{"login", "myUser", "hunter2"}`)

Using exceptions:

```
public void wrapperMethod(Object sender, Object receiver, String[] command) {
    try {
        handleCommand(sender, receiver, command);
    catch(CommandExecutionException e) {
        receiver.sendTo(sender, e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void handleCommand(Object sender, Object receiver, String[] command) {
    if(command.length != 3)
        throw new CommandExecutionException("Things went wrong");
    //Do things
}
```

Not using exceptions:

```
public void wrapperMethod(Object sender, Object receiver, String[] command) {
    handleCommand(sender, receiver, command);
}
private void handleCommand(Object sender, Object receiver, String[] command)
    if(command.length != 3) {
        receiver.sendTo(sender, "Things went wrong");
        return;
    }
    //Do things
}
```

Which type should I prefer and **why**? Right now, I'm thinking of going with exceptions simply because I can save a few lines of code that I really don't need. When a user error is detected, `handleCommand` is always halted immediately. There's also the possiblility of having `handleCommand` return `Optional<Error>` or something like that, but this seems really fishy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer option with exceptions, because it separates normal processing from error handling.

In second option method ***handleCommand*** is responsible for both.

First option follows [Single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle): method ***handleCommand*** handles correct flow, if something goes wrong throw exception and allow someone else cares the problem.

Moreover, assume that within section

> //Do things

you find other error. If you use exception, you may keep consistent and clean pattern that any error triggers exception and someone who catch the exception cares correct handling.

Don't worry that exceptions are expensive; planes are more expensive that bikes, but if you go for vacation to Bali, use rather plane than bike (not applicable for Bali citizens:) ). Exceptions are designed for *exceptions*, as long as you don't use them in *regular* processing, it is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are ***expensive***.  Using them as flow control is strongly discouraged.  It also means that your code could complete abruptly, and makes it harder to debug or read.

I'd go a different route:  use [Hibernate Validators](http://hibernate.org/validator/).  They're not difficult to set up or establish in your code, and using them means that your input is validated before you ever attempt to manipulate things.  It also keeps your validation logic and actual business logic separate.

If you don't want to go that route, I'd encourage the latter approach - although, I'd use an `else` instead of `return` from a `void` method.

Comment: Using `if...else if...else` would nest really deep. There are multiple steps inside `handleCommand` where I need to check for user error, so sometimes there are things that need to be done between multiple checks. I can't really refactor it into many smaller methods as well, because of the nature of the method.

Comment: I'm confident that you can separate your validation logic from your operational/business logic.  This is why I suggested Hibernate Validators.  It really depends on how you've got your method written, but if it's larger than 40 lines, and most of that is just validation, taking the time to split out the pieces that concern input validation is *well* worth it.

Comment: It is 20 lines excluding blanks. I can refactor it into to methods, but that's about it. Hibernate validators don't work for me, since the logic is a bit too complex (depends on the type of the `sender` object etc).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly by the type of sender object, since it's `Object` (and you'd be doing a lot of `instanceof` to see *which* one it is, anyway).  I only threw that out there as a suggestion.  The alternate route is still valid; you shouldn't be using exceptions as flow control.

Comment: `instanceof` is quite common, yeah. Should I think of returning whether the command ran successfully or not (something like a `CommandResult` object)? Just telling the user that they did something wrong sems a little inflexbile, for example when I decide that I need to log when the user makes an error, it would be a lot easier to do with exceptions. Maybe there is an even better solution that you can suggest?